# Prove that a.s.$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{N_t}{t}=\frac{1}{\mu}$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Consider a diligent janitor who replaces a light bulb the instant it burns out. Suppose that the first bulb is put in at time zero and let $X_i$ be the lifetime of the i-th bulb. Suppose $(X_i)_{i\ge 0}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb E[X_1]=\mu<\infty$. Let $S_n=\sum_i^nX_i$, the time that the n-th bulb burns out. For any $t>0$, let $N_t=\sup\{n:S_n\le t\}$ be the number of light bulb  that have been burnt out by time $t$. Prove that a.s.$$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{N_t}{t}=\frac{1}{\mu}$$

The answer should be short, Now it is clear that;

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_1(w)+X_2(w)+...+X_n(w)}{n}=\mu$

and therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{N_t}{\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}X_1}=\frac{1}{\mu}$

but how can I show that ;

$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}X_i}=1$

Comment: Show $S_{N_t} \le t \le S_{N_t+1}$ implies $t/N_t \to \mu.$

Comment: "The answer should be short" Why?

Comment: @Did It is one of our training exercises, and most of them require only a few steps.

Comment: Do you think you will be properly "trained" once you will have handed back their solutions copied from MSE?

Comment: @Did I solved definitely more exercises, than I asked here. Here I needed only a hint, and with the first comment, I think I can solve it, don't bother.

Comment: Then will you write a solution to your question and post it as an answer?